# Licenciamiento Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition

Tags: licencias, oracle-19c

Mi licenciamiento de Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition se encuentra en proceso, al descargar Oracle 19c Enterprise Edition no se me requirio la licencia e incluso lo tengo instalado sin problemas, al realizar pruebas con el, mientras me llega la licencia, encontre los siguientes casos de ERROR y me gustaría conocer si cuando me llegue la licencia estaran resueltos o son problemas de Oracle, a continuación menciono los casos:

1. Mi instancia esta configurada con MAX_STRING_SIZE = EXTENDED, por lo cual el valor máximo de VARCHAR2 o CHAR es de 32767 caracteres, al realizar un cast de un tipo de dato NUMBER a VARCHAR2(32767) o CHAR(32767) obtengo el error Error de E/S: Se ha forzado la interrupción de una conexión existente por el host remoto, y mi instacia se detiene de manera inmediata, solo me ha sucedido con los datos de tipo NUMBER
2. Realice un Query con 511 CASE WHEN y esto ocasiono que la instancia quedara bloqueada, incluso tuve que reiniciar mi equipo, porque el servicio de Oracle consumio toda la memoria RAM

Espero que puedan ayudarme con mis problemas, gracias

Comment: Parece más una pregunta para el soporte de Oracle. Si tienes una licencia, la misma viene con soporte!!!. Mi recomendación es que plantees tu pregunta a la gente de Oracle, en [es.so] buscamos soluciones a problemas específicos de programación, que se puedan reproducir. Lamentablemente tu problema no parece de programación, sino de configuración de un entorno específico. Saludos

Comment: Como mencione al principio aún no cuento con la licencia, es por ello que no puedo hacer la pregunta directamente al soporte de Oracle y recurrí a este foro